# Storing a String in Variable and printing it out in 8086 Assembly language

Tags: emu8086

```
;CODE FOR PRINTING A STRING IN 8086 ASSEMBLY LANGUAGE:

.model small
.stack 100h
.data
 msg db 'hello$'
.code
main proc
    mov dx,@data
    mov ds,dx 

    mov dx,offset msg ;lea dx,msg
    mov ah,9 
    int 21h

    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h  
main endp
end main
```

MY QUESTIONS:

1. db can store 8 bits of data but hello$ is 6 byte in size(1 char= 8 bits). how can it store the string if the string is larger then db's capacity?
2. if i write MOV DX,MSG it shows error(as dx is 8 bit register and the string is larger then it's capacity). but it works when it is written as MOV DX,OFFSET msg or LEA DX,msg. can you explain what offset & lea does?

Comment: Your post needs edit. Read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: `msg db 'hello$'` needs to be after `.data` why have you placed it after `.code` ?

Comment: yes right..i didn't noticed that..by the way can you give the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> db can store 8 bits of data but hello$ is 6 byte in size(1 char= 8 bits). how can it store the string if the string is larger then db's capacity?

It does not store the `hello$` as a whole instead it stores the [OFFSET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Offset_(computer_science)) of `hello$` which in this case is **h** ( starting character of your string ).

**This is how your string will be stored in memory:**

Lets say DS:SI registers ( which point to some memory address/location usually the address of the variable you have declared in your program. ) store address `07200`. And lets assume offset ( 'h' in your case ) has been assigned this address. Now all the other character following the offset will be stored at contiguous memory location so address `07200` will store `h`, `07201` will store `e`, `07202` will store `l` and so on. So in this way `msg` variable will only have to store the offset because it knows it will find all the other character of string following the offset ( arrays are stored in contiguous memory ).

> if i write MOV DX,MSG it shows error(as dx is 8 bit register and the string is larger then it's capacity). but it works when it is written as MOV DX,OFFSET msg or LEA DX,msg. can you explain what offset & lea does?

First of all DX is not 8bit instead its 16bit register and [09h](http://www.ablmcc.edu.hk/%7Escy/CIT/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.htm#int21h_09h) service of `INT 21h` needs an offset of your string to be placed in `DX` register and then from there it keeps printing the characters on the console until it encounters **$** ( string termination character ) so writing `msg DX, MSG` upsets `09h` service of `INT 21h` that is why it throws an error. `mov dx, offset msg` and `lea dx, msg` ( [Load Effect Address](http://www.electronics.dit.ie/staff/tscarff/8086_instruction_set/8086_instruction_set.html#LEA) ) both place the offset of the string in DX register.

Answer (score 0):

offset stores the address of first char. in this case it's 'h'..so dx doesn't hold the whole string but the address of the first char, probably lea also works as offset...that solves the second question if i am right..but how come db store 6 byte char? as it is capable of dealing with 8bits or 1 byte only